# How to combine webpack with ng-build?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am using `webpack.config` to complile, bindle and minify my scss files

```
 module: {
 rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
         use: extractSass.extract({
            use: [{
                loader: "css-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader"
            }],
            // use style-loader in development
            fallback: "style-loader"
        })
    }]
 },
```

The problem now is `ng-build` doesn't run `webpack.config` auto, I have to run `webpack` command then `ng-build`, I need to include `webpack.config` in `ng-build` or create custom command to do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-cli is built on webpack. You can use `ng eject` to remove the ng-cli encapsulation and reveal the webpack configuration underneath.

Comment: I use it and i see the web.config file and i see that it should compile sass files, so why when using ng-build it doesn;t compiled and minified auto ??

Comment: I don't know what you changed in the conf. With a clean new ng-cli project, it does compile sass files automatically. Normally, you don't need to specify it yourself :/

Comment: Yes you are right, i tried it now and i can see but i see that it converts everything to .js files no CSS, why it doing that ? and is it a way to just convert it to normal css files

Comment: With ng-cli, you don't need the css files. If you really want them, you can use node-sass or an other standalone sass library to manually compile your sass outside the ng-cli.

Comment: But now by doing it with this way, I am losing the caching feature of CSS files as Everytime it will be loaded from js to DOM, right ??

Comment: I don't know. I think the Angular team knows what they are doing. I hope ^^ Actually, if you use `styleUrls` in your component, even if you target CSS file, Angular transforms it to JS at runtime. So you better let ng-cli building it before deploying to avoid the runtime compilation.